# How can I do a round button, with one side being even, straight? (Image)

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, sass

Hey question is in the title:) I want it to be like in the picture here. Is there any way to accomplish that?

[image]

Comment: You gotta try it. People are going to downvote you for lack of effort. Stack overflow is for helping with bugs/issues. Not doing your homework will get you swift downvotes, friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `border-radius` and set a value:

```
.element {
  border-radius:15px;
}
```

Or you can set specific values for each corner, as mentioned above.

```
.element {
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `border-radius` for individual corners, like `border-top-right-radius: 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<style>
i{

}

.btn-group-lg>.btn, .btn-lg {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 1.3333333;
    border-radius: 30px;
}

</style>

<body style="margin-top:50px;">

<div class="container"> 
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
      <i class="fa fa-map-pin fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>   |   <i class="fa fa-globe fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSS selector border-radius allows you to set the value for all 4 corners of a rectangle. This selector allows you to select which corners are rounded and the degree of roundness they have. The degree is changed by the px size, as that is the radius of the semi-circle, so the larger the value the greater the roundness of the corners.

```
.all-four-corners {border-radius: 5px, 5px, 5px, 5px;}
.top-corners {border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;}
.bottom-corners {border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;}
.right-corners {border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;}
.left-corners {border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a round button with oneside straight using `border-radius: 0px 50% 50% 0px;`